# php variable in file path string

Tags: php

I have the following php code:

```
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'file.pem');
```

and I'm trying to do this:

```
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', '$var.pem');
```

but it is not accessing the .pem file correctly when I do it that way.

How do I add a variable and append .pem to the end of it in this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the below code:

```
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $var.'.pem');
```

what ever you specify between the single open inverted commas will be appended as it is to the `$var` variable. It can 'pem' or '.pem' or any other string.

**Note:** What ever that you give in the single inverted commas is always considered a string in PHP, even '$var' is considered as a string not a PHP variabe

Answer (score 3):

Use double quotes instead of single quote. Single quote doesn't process php variable inside but that double quotes does.

```
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', "$var.pem");
```

Or you can do something like this:

```
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $var.'.pem');
```

It's string concatenation if you really love that single quote.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on @Sourabh's answer, you can also use interpolation with explicit notation, like so:

```
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', "{$var}.pem");
```

Interpolation is slightly slower, but it *is an option*.